# How can I make an android xml layout for Category and CategoryItem

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I'am new in using java and android studio and i was wondering how can i make a layout like this in 1 activity. [myImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcGlT.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried so far? StackOverflow is not a 'Code this for me'-site.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a Listview adapter

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    List<Product> products;
    private Activity context;

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return products.size();
    }

    public ExampleAdapter(List<Product> products, Activity context) {
        this.products = products;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return products.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final Product product = products.get(position);

        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_shopping_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.getProductTextView().setText(product.getName());
        holder.getProductImageView(). setImageResource(product.getPicture());

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        private final TextView productTextView;
        private final ImageView productImageView;

        private ViewHolder(View wrapperView) {
            productTextView = (TextView) wrapperView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            productImageView = (TextView) wrapperView.findViewById(R.id.ivPicture);

        }

        public TextView getProductTextView() {
            return productTextView;
        }

        public ImageView getProductImageView() {
            return productImageView;
        }

    }
}
```

This adapter needs a layout to define what the rows will look like. This will be something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/ivPicture"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:text="Product 1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Lastly in your activity where you want to display the overview you will need to use a listview and set the adapter

```
final ExampleAdapter adapter = new ExampleAdapter(list, this);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: how can i switch between the 2 layouts with only 1 activity?

Comment: You can do so by putting each layout in a separate Fragment.

Comment: You can find more info on this here https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html