# How to send data From One RecyclerView Item to load another RecyclerView using Nested JSON

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I am developing a Cinema App, but I want to use 2 RecyclerViews, one has successfully loaded, it contains the list of cinemas, then I want when someone taps on any of the Cinemas it loads another list of RecyclerView containing Movies.

How can I deal with 2 RecyclerViews?

Am new in Android. Below is the link to the sample of codes:

This is the link of the sample codes

[RecyclerView Item to Load Another RecyclerView with Nested JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38812637/recyclerview-item-to-load-another-recyclerview-with-nested-json)

Answer (score 0):

You have to options here:

1. The two recycler views are displayed on the screen at the same time.

This will imply the data in the 2nd recylcler view need the ability to change multiple times.

Add this code in your onItemSelectListener from your cinemaRecyclerView

```
Cinema selectedCinema = cinemas.get(selectedPosition); // This is the selected cinema from the CinemaRecyclerView;
moviesAdapter.updateMovies(selectedCinema.getMovies);
```

In your MovieAdapter class add the following method.

```
public void updateMovies(List<Movie> movies){
    this.movies.clear();
    this.movies.addAll(movies);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

2. The cinema recycler view is on one screen and the movies list is on the next screen.

Here you will need to pass the selected Cinema object to the next Activity/Fragment. Based on this selection you can directly instantiate your MoviesAdapter with the correct movies list.

Comment: Thanks so much @MrJM , can you please try to implement it in  the `CinemaAdapter.java` class , coz its making me confused , am new in Android

Comment: Please and please,  help me out with that.

Comment: If you follow my answer here you will have a good example http://stackoverflow.com/a/38831490/1185811